# linux-5.8.13 kernel struck at Loading Initial Ramdisk screen

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have legion y540. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Downloaded the latest stable release which was linux-5.8.13 and installed on my Laptop.

When i tried to boot this Kernel, i only see two messages on screen

```
Loading Kernel
Loading Initial Ramdisk
```

How to resolve this issue

Comment: Remove the `quiet` kernel boot option - try again. Report what you see.

Comment: I tried removing quiet splash nomodeset, still no change

Comment: Add these options `efi=debug earlycon=efifb keep_bootcon`

Comment: No change. Same behavior

Comment: File a bug report

Comment: Website please where I can file

Comment: Its vanilla kernel. Can we file it in ubuntu bugzilla

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: Thanks. Created a bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209591